# How to use Visibility on Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout

Think I have four buttons, I want to click one button which will visible some items and at the same time it will invisible/gone others three buttons data. How can I do that please send me sample code.

Comment: Did you do some research? https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#attr_android:visibility

Comment: Hi Welcome to stack overflow please read [how-to-ask?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) . Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem. For help with this, read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Hi Nahian Ahmed! Since you're new to StackOverflow you don't know how you can elaborate what you need to get done  and you don't know how to format your questions in a way that looks nice to reader. I'd recommend you to edit your question and explain what you need in details, don't be shy to put some code you already have, that'll help others to understand what you have and what do you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Show view

```
myView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)
```

hide view

```
myView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)
or
myView.setVisibility(View.GONE)
```